# Nested SELECT to find highest value and display 0 if not found

Tags: mysql, select, nested, max

Thank you stackoverflow community!  I have learned SO much from you over the years and I've recently created an account.  I hope the answer to this question isn't obviously somewhere already, but I am going to go crossed eyed if I read another post.  Here's my problem:

I recently used a nested SELECT to get the highest score for each of my students from a table.  I did so by a little trick another post taught me.  I can't find the exact post I learned it from, but here is a snippet that's essentially the same trick.  I imagine, if you are well versed in sql, it's nothing new to you:

```
SELECT id, authorId, answer, votes
FROM (  SELECT id, authorId, answer, votes
        FROM answers
        ORDER BY votes DESC) AS h
GROUP BY authorId
```

The ORDER BY ____ DESC makes the last value, the highest overwrite all previous, so you end up with only it...if I understand correctly.  So, that was great and I tailored it to my needs.  The only problem is, now, I'd like to add one more feature to it and I'm racking my brain cells over it.  I'm hoping some generous person will just straighten me out.  I want to get a complete list of students from my "rosters" table and if there is no score for a given student, in my "holder" table, I'd like it to display a "0".  Here is what I have, and I don't know exactly how to tweak it to do just that:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM (
      SELECT
      holder.id,
      #IFNULL(holder.score, 0) AS score,
      holder.score AS score,
      holder.total,
      holder.student_id AS stu_id,
      holder.date AS date,
      users.firstname AS first,
      users.lastname AS last,
      users.stu_number AS stuno,
      assignments.name AS test,
      rosters.p_id,
      preps.period AS period,
      preps.user

      FROM holder

      JOIN rosters
      ON rosters.stu_id = holder.student_id

      JOIN users
      ON users.id = holder.student_id

      JOIN assignments
      ON assignments.id = holder.t_id

      JOIN preps
      ON preps.id = rosters.p_id

      WHERE holder.visible = 0
      AND preps.user = 1
      AND assignments.user = 1
      AND holder.t_id = 1
      AND preps.period = 2
      ORDER BY score DESC
      ) x
 GROUP BY stuno
 ORDER BY last
```

You can see that line I commented out is one of my feeble attempts to get it to display a "0" if NULL, but it's not working.  I get a complete list, but if the score isn't found for a student, that student isn't showing up in my list.  Anyone have a solution/idea for me to try?

Am I overusing JOINs and making my life harder than it needs to be?  I'm mostly self-taught, so I know I have some holes in the fundamentals.  It hasn't stopped me from creating some crazy cool projects though...but every now and then I'm sure I'm causing myself some unnecessary grief.

///////////////////////////////////////////////

Here is what I have done with the answer below, so that it grabs info from my tables:

```
SELECT au.stu_id, 
    COALESCE(t.id, 0) as id,
    COALESCE(t.score , 0) as score               
 FROM rosters au
 LEFT JOIN  (
    SELECT *
         FROM (
           SELECT a.*, 
              @rownum := if(@prev_value = student_id, 
              @rownum + 1, 
           1) rn,
         @prev_value := student_id as prev    
         FROM holder a, 
        (SELECT @rownum := 0, @prev_value := '') r
      ORDER BY student_id, score DESC
    ) T
  WHERE T.rn = 1) T  
ON au.stu_id = T.student_id
```

So, this is working great, except it doesn't show students who don't have scores for a given test.  If their score isn't found in the "holder" table, I'd like it to show up as a "0".

/////////////////

Wait a minute!  I may have mispoke...I think it is working correctly.  I'll need to tweak a few things and get back to you.  By the way, thanks SO much for taking the time to help me!

Answer (score 1):

Your first aproach only work because a bad design on MySQL.

The right aproach should be

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4a5bc/5)**

```
SELECT a.id, a.authorId, a.answer, a.votes
FROM (  SELECT authorId, 
               MAX(votes) as votes
        FROM answers
        GROUP BY authorId ) AS h
JOIN answers a
  ON a.authorId = h.authorId
 AND a.votes = h.votes;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| id | authorId | answer | votes |
|----|----------|--------|-------|
|  2 |        a |     x2 |    21 |
|  4 |        b |     x1 |    23 |  ==> 
|  5 |        b |     x2 |    23 |  ==> duplicates max value are possible
```

But this have issue if several answer has same score. You need to include some logic to decide which one to show.

Also you can use variable to get the highest score.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT a.*, 
            @rownum := if(@prev_value = authorId, 
                          @rownum + 1, 
                          1) rn,
            @prev_value := authorId as prev    
      FROM answers a, 
            (SELECT @rownum := 0, @prev_value := '') r
      ORDER BY authorId, votes DESC
     ) T
WHERE T.rn = 1;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| id | authorId | answer | votes | rn | prev |
|----|----------|--------|-------|----|------|
|  4 |        b |     x1 |    23 |  1 |    b | => only one is show but would      
|  2 |        a |     x2 |    21 |  1 |    a |    be random unless you specify some rule.
```

Now for your question you also need to use **[LEFT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)** instead of `JOIN` to get the students without scores.

Something like this

```
SELECT au.authorId, 
       COALESCE(t.id, 0) as id,
       COALESCE(t.answer , 0) as answer ,
       COALESCE(t.votes , 0) as votes               
FROM authors au
LEFT JOIN  (
            SELECT *
            FROM (
                  SELECT a.*, 
                        @rownum := if(@prev_value = authorId, 
                                      @rownum + 1, 
                                      1) rn,
                        @prev_value := authorId as prev    
                  FROM answers a, 
                        (SELECT @rownum := 0, @prev_value := '') r
                  ORDER BY authorId, votes DESC
                 ) T
            WHERE T.rn = 1) T  
      ON au.authorId = T.authorId
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| authorId | id | answer | votes |
|----------|----|--------|-------|
|        a |  2 |     x2 |    21 |
|        b |  4 |     x1 |    23 |
|        c |  0 |      0 |     0 |
```

Comment: @Strawberry I can include the `COALESCE` but what alias Im missing?

Comment: Okay, I have to say, your sql writing skills are WAY beyond my feeble level.  I was almost too intimidated to try and modify everything to match the "schema" or whatever of my tables, but I actually succeeded.  It now spits out everything as it should with one exception.  If the student exists in my rosters table, but doesn't have a score in the holder table, the student just doesn't show up in the list.

Comment: Try create your schema in sqlFiddle and I will take a look later.

Comment: @fredericpool change 'where' to 'and'

Comment: Ok, I haven't been working on this problem since I left work Friday, but I WILL try creating a schema in sqlFiddle as Juan suggests and I'll also see what happens if I change my WHERE to AND as Strawberry suggests.  So thankful for the advice!  I love learning this stuff...

Comment: Okay, I've never used sqlFiddle before, but I think it will teach me a lot.  Here is the link to my schema and the select statement I tried to modify to work with my schema.  [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea6924d/5)

Comment: So what result you want with that data?

Comment: What I would like is a complete list from the ROSTERS table and for each of those I would like to see a MAX score from the HOLDER table.  For each score that doesn't exist in the holder table, I'd like to see a zero.  I feel I'm very close, but something is just beyond my reach.  I took the query you wrote, which was at least a couple steps more advanced than what I'm used to creating on my own and tried to modify it to match my tables and column names...but I still don't quite get what I need.  I totally admire your skill and appreciate all the help.

Comment: That doesnt tell me what you need, create an excel sheet and put the result you want and take a picture. So i know what to do.